# In Python, how to refactor a loop?

Tags: python, list, sympy

I construct a Newton polynomial for a function. It has a fairly simple structure:

[image: Newton 's polynomial formula]

Here, the deltas for `y` are taken from the `string_one list`, and `x_0` - for each block-summands have different values (from the `x_col_list list`) - actually, this is indicated by non-steps in square brackets: `[1] [2] [n]`.

I'm trying to build a formula where:

1. `x` remains `x` without getting values (this is served by the `sympy` module);
2. the denominator of each fraction increases by one;
3. element `(x - x_0)` in each summand-block we add one additional bracket, keeping the already accumulated:

   (−0)
   (−0)*(−0.3142)
   (−0)*(−0.3142)(−0.6283)

   ## with the last term:

   (−0)*(−0.3142)(−0.6283)(−0.9425)(−1.2566)(−1.5708)(−1.885)(−2.1991)

I'm in trouble right now:

1. I get too much in the opposite direction: `(-2.1991)(-1.885)...(−0.3142)`
2. `x` with `zero` is immediately truncated to `x`, and I need `(x - 0)`
3. and somehow now it has to be folded.

Code:

```
from sympy import symbols, prod
from scipy.special import factorial

x = symbols('x')

string_one = [0.3091,-0.0304,-0.0271,0.0054,0.0025,-0.0016,0.0019,-0.0046,0.0099,-0.019]
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]
h=1.25665

x = symbols('x')

 # we go along the deltas:
num=1
for delta in string_one:
    # we go along the column of x's: 
    polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 ) * prod([x - args for args in x_col_list[::-1]])
    num+=1
    print(polynom)
```

Now the way out is this:
`0.246*x*(x - 2.5133)*(x - 2.1991)*(x - 1.885)*(x - 1.5708)*(x - 1.2566)*(x - 0.9425)*(x - 0.6283)*(x - 0.3142) -0.0096*x*(x - 2.5133)*(x - 2.1991)...`

As you can see, brackets are attached to each term. And all the other flaws. What can be done? Thanks

Comment: Possibly related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413476/in-python-how-do-i-add-an-incrementing-element-of-a-polynomial

Comment: Something like this might help for making `x - 0`: `Add(x, Mul(-1, 0, evaluate=False), evaluate=False)`